# Storing Data Using Nested Structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am attempting to store navigation information for a text-based menu system, and am unsure of the best way to do it. Each menu has been given a state number, and contains several commands, each of which leads to another state. The number of commands varies with each state, as does the length of the command - "1", "Y", "myfilename" all being valid commands at various points.

My current thinking is to use a nested structure, and use pointers to cope with
the variable command length/quantity:

```
// Smallest useful unit - a single command-state pair
typedef struct {
    char *command;
    uint16 next_state;
} cs;

cs test1 = {"1", 100};
cs test2[] = {{"foo", 200}, {"bar", 201}};

// Every command-state pair for a particular state
typedef struct {
    uint8 command_count;
    cs *all_cs[];
} one_state;

one_state all_states[NUMBER_OF_STATES];
```

What I would like is to store the navigation information in such a way that
its easy to index through the commands for a particular state in order to
test if the user has entered a valid command or not.

Is there a better way, or am I on the right track? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but you might want to try replacing the (fairly arbitrary) uint16 next_state with a one_state* so you can refer to each state by name. I do not see any uint16 "state number" variable in the one_state struct, so I'm not sure how you're planning to use next_state.

You can look into state machine implementations in C, but most will be optimized for speed and not readability.

If you clarify exactly how you're planning to use this data structure, I can be more helpful.

Comment: Ah - I now understand why you were confused. That would be because what I was attempting to do was ridiculous. I did as you suggested and had a look at state machine implementations, and am now on the right track. Thank you!